# Every digits in number of a range should be is divisible by n

Tags: java

Here I need to check if every digit in the number,For a range  should be divisible by 3 that means when I have typed down 20 and 40 ,the code need to verify every digit of the number between 20 to 40, and it should display 30,33,36,39

What I tried to do is to get the last digit of the code and check if it is divisible,I am stuck in mind way

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the range for shipment numbers :");
        int n;
        int Duplicate = 0;
        int count = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int range1 = sc.nextInt();
        int range2 = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i = range1; i <= range2; i++){
            int num = i;
            int length = String.valueOf(i).length();
            Duplicate = 0;

            for(int j = 1; j <= length; j++)
            {
                n = num % 10;
                num = num / 10;

                if(n % 3 == 0 && i % 3 == 0 ){
                    Duplicate = Duplicate+1;
                    count = count+1;

                    System.out.println(rep);
                    if (Duplicate <= 1)
                        System.out.println(i);
                }
            }

            if (count <= 0)
                System.out.println("Shipment numbers unavailable");
            if (count <= 0)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about 21, 24 and 27?

Comment: as 2 and 1 the individual digits are not divisible by 3 it should not print those values

Comment: Why not simply test if `num % 3 == 0`? That's sufficient...

Comment: he doesn't appear to want to see if you can divide it by 3, he wants to see if you can divide each digit by 3. I agree that the question could have been worded better though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you do odd stuff with the modulo operator. We do not care if `i` can be divided by 3 or not.

You also use a lot of variables I don't understand, like `Duplicate`.

Or

```
for(int j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
    num = num / 10;
}
```

Which I like to write as

```
while (num > 0) {
    num = num / 10;
}
```

It's just that it uses less variables.

Anyway, here's the complete code, I added some booleans in to make it look like requested.

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the range for shipment numbers :");
        int n;
        boolean first = true;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int range1 = sc.nextInt();
        int range2 = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i = range1; i <= range2; i++){
            int num = i;
            boolean numberIsAwesome = true;

            while (num > 0)
            {
                n = num % 10;

                if(n % 3 != 0){
                    numberIsAwesome = false;
                }

                num = num / 10;
            }

            if (numberIsAwesome) {
                if (!first) {
                    System.out.print(", ");
                }
                System.out.print(i);
                first = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to check whether each digit is divisible by 3 you can replace your loop by the following code. It just goes the digits right-to left and uses a boolean to remember whether all digits encountered so far were all divisible by 3 by using a logical AND.

```
    for (int i = range1; i <= range2; i++) {
        int num = i;
        boolean isDivisible = true;

        while (num > 0) { 
            // get last (rightmost) digit to inspect
            int n = num % 10;

            isDivisible = isDivisible && (n % 3 == 0);
            // integer-divide by 10 to prepare for next round
            num = num / 10; 
        } 

        if (isDivisible) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

A weakness of the shown code is that, just like your original, it looks at the entire number, where it could bail out as soon as the criterium divisible by 3 isn't met, but that's easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. Convert the number to a String. Split the string into a String[] then convert each character back to an int and check if it is divisible by 3.

```
for(int i = range1; i <= range2; i++){
     boolean isDivisible = true;
     for (String value : String.valueOf(i).split("")) {
         if (Integer.valueOf(value) % 3 != 0) {
             isDivisible = false;
             break;
         } 
     } 

     if (isDivisible)  System.out.println("Is divisible: " + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I offer to use `String.valueOf(i)` to receive number digits:

```
public static Set<Integer> getDivisibleBy(int from, int to, int div) {
    IntPredicate isDivisibleBy = val -> {
        if (val % div != 0)
            return false;

        for (char ch : String.valueOf(val).toCharArray())
            if ((ch - '0') % div != 0)
                return false;

        return true;
    };

    return IntStream.rangeClosed(from, to).filter(isDivisibleBy).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I skipped the scanner part, but leveraging the code with some Java 8 streams and lambda's can drastically reduce code and result in better readability and maintainability;

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(20, 40)
    .boxed()
    .filter(digit -> {
        boolean wholeDivisable = digit % 3 == 0;
        boolean partlyDivisable = Arrays.stream(digit.toString().split(""))
                .allMatch(strDigit -> Integer.valueOf(strDigit) % 3 == 0);

        return wholeDivisable && partlyDivisable;
    })
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

`IntStream.rangeClosed:` create a stream of intsbetween 20 and 40

`boxed():` box int to Integer as we want to split it as a string in our partlyDivisable check. `toString()` reads better than `(digit+"").split("")`.

`filter:` filter the stream of Integer checking both of divisable as a whole + each digit seperately

`forEach:` for each leftover element, print to sout

Comment: Note that using streams is slower than classic loops so you should weigh the benefits.